# Ctrl button deselects search bars and other text entry boxes in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (i.e. for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) deselects the search bar and I end up highlighting the whole page instead of the text in the search bar. I have reset all Keyboard Shortcuts in **Settings** > **Devices** > **Keyboard**. This is a fresh install and the problem has been present since the install.

The problem is present in all applications (Document Viewer, Firefox, etc) and all text entry boxes (search bars, search in page bars, even this comment box).

Answer (score 3):

I'm an idiot! I did change some features after the install, I used this (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) and in '**Keyboard & Mouse**' turned on the '*Pointer Location: Press the ctrl key to highlight the pointer.*' Turning this off fixed my problem.